# Outlook Change credentials password used for Mailbox - Windows 10

Tags: microsoft-outlook, credentials, mailbox

I know it sounds wierd but I want to know how to change / correct / forget the credentials used for a mailbox login in Outlook 2019 (Office 365) on Windows 10.

Here is the story. At our company we needed to add a new mailbox to 4 people. Let's call it ABC@mailbox.com. After going to File > Add Account & entering the new mailbox, selecting Exchange, I reopened Outlook to get asked for the credentials. So far no issues. But when I entered the credentials for ABC and checked "Remember this login" it asked me again but for another mailbox (DEF@mailbox.com). I thought I made a typo and enter the same as for ABC and overwrote the login credentials for DEF@mailbox.com which was previously working fine.

Of course now I get the info that Outlook cannot connect anymore and I have no other choice but to create a new mail profile and redo everything. Luckily this guy only got his mailbox (DEF), the new mailbox (ABC) and his personal .pst for archiving.

So my question is, how do you trigger that Outlook asks again for those credentials or how can you update them?

The best thing I found was this, but this does no longer seem to apply.
https://kb.rice.edu/page.php?id=107356

Comment: What is the OS? Windows? Mac? Mobile?

Comment: @LPChip I have updated the question. It's Windows 10 and Office 365 / Outlook 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows, the credentials for Office365 / Outlook 2019 are stored in Credential Manager.

Credential Manager can be accessed through the control panel (show all icons) or by searching for Credential Manager in the start menu.

Do note that it may be called differently if your windows language is not English.

From here, go to the tab windows credentials. You can edit or remove stored credentials there.

Comment: Ah. I should have thought of it. Will try this next time. ;)
Will do a test ant check if it works. If it works, you will be marked as answer.

Comment: Should work. I've fixed many issues like that. Do note, in rare occasions, its a different problem. In the Account tab in excel, word, etc... you may have multiple accounts logged in and you only see one. You then need to log out all accounts and login with the correct account again that has the licence.

Comment: Sadly it didn't help me. I had to remove the entries and it seems that  because of this the whole Outlook profile needed to be created again as it wouldn't let me open outlook at all. It's really annoying that Microsoft didn't add an Account Settings Option to let you change the credentials or to prompt for credentials on the next login. :/

Comment: That should definitely not have happened. Sounds like something is wrong in the profile then.

Comment: Managed to get it to work after another attempt. I removed all the credentials linked to the outlook profile and then it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the issue mentioned in this thread?

[Outlook Desktop App Sign-In At Startup](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/784236/outlook-desktop-app-sign-in-at-startup.html)

Comment: Yeah this was basically what I needed. Took me another attempt to get it work.